# Blazor-Server Notifications with BlazorHub in base path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make the client side receive notifications in realtime using BlazorHub. In all the example that I have found, a hub gets mapped to it's own path like

```
endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
```

but in my case the notification icon is on the top navbar which is shared by the whole app and visible at all time, like in Facebook for example.
I tried mapping it to `/_Host` or `/` but it throws exceptions when I try to build the `ConnectionHub` that the url could not be determined.

The line `endpoints.MapBlazorHub();` says it maps the blazorhub to the default path, do i have to use this one? if so, how?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server

Comment: How does this address the case in my question?

Comment: It clearty shows you need both: ` endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");`

Comment: Yeah i noticed that, but in my case the notifications are a component without a route, because is placed in the navbar (top of the page) which is shared by all other pages...

Comment: That URL is not referring to a route in your app, that is how the connection to SignalR on your server is made.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat")` like telling the server: "Hey! Start listening for SignalR connections at this address!".

In order to listen for notification from your server you create a `HubConnection` that points to `/chat`. Before you start the connection with `hubConnection.StartAsync()`, you should register your events with `hubConnection.On()`.

Take a look at the article linked by Brian in the comments.